# Jquery Form Submit: infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Hello and good day everyone.

I have a question and I already have a working answer. I am looking for the EXPLANATION for the ANSWER.

I have a normal html page with a form, the submit button for the form has function on its onclick event
e.g.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="envoke()">Login</button>
```

In my javascript file I have the following code

```
function envoke ()
{
  $('form:first').submit((e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      loginAnimation();
  })
}

function loginAnimation()
{
  let w = window.innerWidth;
  $('#DIVbody').css({"position" : "relative"}).animate({left : "-=" + w + "px"}),2000,function () {
       $('form').first().submit();
  }
}
```

This code however results in an infinite loop as envoke() function keeps getting called and in turn the loginAnimation() function gets called.

The idea of the code is to prevent the normal submit of the form, then do the animation that takes 2seconds to complete and AFTER the animation is completed the form should be submitted.

I figured out a fix by changing code in the loginAnimation() function:
`$('form').first().submit();` changed to `$('form').off().first().submit();`
AND IT WORKS!!

However I do not know why and for the life of me I cannot figure it out.
Can anyone please give a simple explanation or material I can go research in order to get a better idea.

PS. Also this is an old project I am working on and I remembered that the envoke() and loginAnimation() functions used to work perfectly, now (about 2months later) it doesn't work and I have to add that little bit of extra Jquery to get it working and the curiosity is killing me on why.

Comment: Because `.off()` removes all event handler that were attached with `.on()` and `.submit()`is a shortcut for `.on('submit', handler)`. Sources: https://api.jquery.com/off/; https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: I appreciate your  answer and  feedback I will have a look Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, `evoke()` is calling `loginAnimate()` which is calling `evoke()` again.

In `evoke()` you are actually binding `loginAnimate()` which will call the binder again. [infinite loop]

[image]

```
function envoke ()
{
  $('form:first').submit((e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      loginAnimation();
  })
}

function loginAnimation()
{
  let w = window.innerWidth;
  $('#DIVbody').css({"position" : "relative"}).animate({left : "-=" + w + "px"}),2000,function () {
       // $('form').first().submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Azevedo I appreciate your answer and I was suspecting that, just wanted another voice confirming my mind thought haha. tx